# MS Project 2013 - Add-in vs App for Office

Tags: sharepoint-2013, ms-project, office-2013

is it possible to update values in cells in MS Standard/Professional with the use of App for Office? Or should I use Project-Add in then?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you mean new "Agave" JS API for Project 2013 task pane apps - it is very weak, compared to VSTO add-ins API. There's no way to change anything using this new API. All of its usage scenarios are related to reading Project data only.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp161143.aspx#pj15_AgaveForProject_Scenarios